# Can't delete anything in the Backoffice

Tags: umbraco5

I've been developing complex websites with Sitecore for the past 4 years, but Umbraco is completely new to me.

I've setup Umbraco 5 (multiple releases of it, including the very latest) on my machine.  I've created a Document Type called **Test**.  When I right-click it and choose **Delete** nothing happens.  This is the case for **anything** that I try to delete in the Backoffice.

I then tried setting up Umbraco 4.7.2 and tried creating something in the Backoffice and deleting.  That worked!  It's only in Umbraco 5 that I can't delete anything.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I haven't found a solution to my problem, but I have narrowed down the issue to be my full local version of IIS running on my Windows 7 64-bit machine.  This issue does not exist when I launch the Umbraco Backoffice on IIS Express.

Comment: In addition, the issue does not exist when I run the same exact files in my Windows 7 64-bit VM using SQL Express 2012 and the full version of IIS 7 that comes with Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: try webmatrix just for checking that it is a permission issue or version issue of IIS.

Comment: Umbraco 5 is essentially broken in other ways for the time being too, it's certainly not release-worthy (even though released as such). Anyway, permissions is worth checking, and also that your Document Type isn't being used (did you create a content node using the type? If so, it has a history and must stay forever! (until you manually clean the db)). Other than that, it's all AJAX, check your browser console and see if anything relevant is output.

Answer (score 0):

Can you save, move or rename your templates?

It sounds like a permissions problem.

Try both of these approaches:

1. Set correct permissions for IUSR on the root folder.
2. Make sure your application in ISS is running on the defaul appPool
3. Use the command prompt and navigate to the root folder and run the following code or paste the code to a .bat file in the root directory and run it.

   ```
   icacls App_Data /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)M icacls App_Plugins /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)M

   icacls Areas /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)R

   icacls bin /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)R

   icacls Content /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)M

   icacls Scripts /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)M

   icacls Views /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)M

   icacls web.config /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)M

   icacls web.config /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":M

   icacls packages.config /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)M

   icacls packages.config /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":M
   ```